# CML equation - from where does the square come from?

Tags: portfolio, capm

In his textbook Asset management Andrew Ang uses the following CML formula (chapter 6)

E(rm) - rf = y * σ^2
Where y is risk aversion factor

What is the source of square?
When I look at CML graph there is a straight line of E(rm) versus σ so I would expect equation to be
E(rm) - rf = y * σ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. We usually plot $E(r_m)$ against $\sigma_m$.
But Ang is making a different point there.

Any investor $i$ with Mean-Variance preferences should optimally hold the following fraction of wealth on the market portfolio:

$$w_i^\star = \frac{r_m - r_f}{\gamma_i \sigma^2_m}$$

The formula above comes directly from maximizing:

$$\max_{w_i} E(r_p) - \frac{\gamma_i}{2}\sigma^2(r_p)$$

where $$E(r_p) = w_i E(r_m) + (1-w_i)) r_f$$

Now if you aggregate the first equation across all investors, because in equilibrium and in aggregate we have to hold the market we have $$\sum_{i=1}^I w_i = 1$$ thus:

$$1 = \sum_{i=1}^I  \frac{E(r_m) - r_f}{\gamma_i \sigma^2_m}$$

$$\bar{\gamma} \sigma^2_m = E(r_m) - r_f$$